# How much recycled yeast to use?

Tags: yeast, pitching

Morning all,

I am just getting into re-using my yeast and have a question.

I wash it as per the YouTube advice that I found (haha) and it seems to store pretty well so far. I have tried it in one batch so far and I put in about half of the yeast I got out of a previous brew, (which was a huge amount more than I put in).

I brew in 50 litre batches, so what would anyone recommend/guess as a good amount of yeast to pitch into this amount of beer?

I normally use 2 x Wyeast smackpacks and my English Pale Ale I am using the recycled yeast in, is generally about 1058.

Should I put in the same amount as with fresh yeast?

Cheers for any thoughts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the calculator at www.mrmalty.com.  It gives you a way to calculate the amount of slurry to use.  BTW, it's generally recognized there is no advantage to rinsing your yeast and could even be a source of contamination.

Comment: Nice one. Many thanks Denny. I will have a look at Mr.malty. Interesting not rinsing, first time I heard that. I am going to just brew my EPA for a while now, so not rinsing sounds like a good plan for a lazy man :) 

Cheers!

Comment: I an VERY lazy!  I rinsed yeast for a while, but finally gave it up and just started pouring the entire slurry into sanitized containers and saving it in the fridge.  No difference at all in beer quality, so I stopped rinsing.

Comment: Nice one. Many thanks Denny. The answer is 257ml -500ml of slurry yeast for 50 litres of ale :)))

Interesting not rinsing, first time I heard that. I am going to just brew my EPA for a while now, so not rinsing sounds like a good plan for a lazy man :)

Cheers!
OK, un-rinsed Burton Ale 1203 yeast now in my EPA from yesterday and (hopefully) they are now in there doing their thang. Cheers!